# Baby Pigeon looks sick and shaking head [Need Help]

Tags: birds, veterinarian

The baby pigeon I rescued 4 days ago was fine and this morning I saw him shaking head like [this](https://youtu.be/PBTy9rj90-Y). Current situation is that it is breathing erratically with eyes closed.

I want to identify what could be the reason and what can I possibly do?

P.S There is no vet around my area

---

(update) The baby pigeon passed away, when I came back from work it was lying on the floor on its back side, breathing with eyes closed as if its in pain. I couldnt do anything and stood helpless. I want to know what could have I done to save him?

(update) I am only looking for "possible" condition based on symptoms presented only as thorough examination isnt possible.

Comment: I'm not a vet so I cannot offer an answer, but my guess is that the bird has some infection. Maybe a respiratory infection, that would explain the erratic breathing. Unfortunately there is not much to do from my perspective. You can try to keep it hydrated by offering drops of water with a pipette or small straw, but don't force the bird to drink or it may get water in the lungs.

Comment: @Elmy, thanks for the comment. I fed it food by making small wet bread portions and opening its mouth to feed it. I also give him little around 0.3ml water (with 1ml pipette) it seemed fine, so shall I rule out that I am responsible for such condition? Could there be a possibliity that the water could have gone to its lungs and thats why it shaking head as shown in video?

Comment: this site https://www.thayerbirding.com/what-do-baby-pigeons-eat/ says that baby pigeons need the enzymes and fats that the parents produce in their crop. Alternatives are macadamia nut milk or dairy-free baby cereal or puppy biscuits mixed with water.

Comment: @Elmy Thanks for this, I just arrived home seeing him lying on its back still breathing but possibly in pain, I feel helpless. Looks like the baby pigeon might not survive :(

Comment: @user0193 oh my... I'm very sorry.